# C++ ifstream reading in a double

Tags: c++, double, long-integer, ifstream

### Scenario:

So I am reading in a file into ifstream that is binary file.
The data in the file includes strings and doubles.
I have to keep track of how many bytes I read so I can not get out of step with the strings / doubles definition.

### Problem:

It seems no matter how I read the data in, it is just garbage or 0.
I have verified the quality of the binary though with another application that reads this specific format.

### Current Methods:

```
ifstream in;
in.open(path, ios::binary);

char * valueBytes = new char[8];
ifs.read((char*)valueBytes,8);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the writing bit? Perhaps that is where the bug is?

Comment: Are sizes of strings and doubles fixed?

Comment: Why are you doing it like this? if you want to read a double, read a double.
`double val; ifs.read((char*)&val, sizeof(val));`

Comment: @EdHeal I suspect it's in some other application.

Comment: Have you checked the ifstream for errors? You don't in your snippet, you may well just be failing to open the file.

Comment: the doubles are strictly 8 bytes, the strings have multiple lengths, however they have a bit describing that length. It is not getting out of step.

Comment: Thanks @SergeyA I tried that previously as well, got 0.0 so thought it wasn't working. 
I'll keep at this and respond with my solution. Thanks it may be my interpretation of the bytes rather than the reading that is failing. D:

Comment: Figured it out!! Posted solution. Was mainly a Big Endian issue (that was really throwing my debugging ability, as I was expecting to see a certain hex or doubles to be interpreted properly (they don't on a little endian system), for example @SergeyA's solution should have worked, it did not.

Comment: We have no idea what your input format is ("binary file" says nothing). Apparently, neither do you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

This was a multi-tiered issue! D:

### First issue

**doubles** are stored in binary stream as **long** int (same byte size you see). So straight up trying to extract a double was failing every time. I had to move to extract a long first.

So code to read in the long from the char * buffer

```
long readLongLittleEndian(char * readBuffer, int length) {

    long value =
    static_cast<uint64_t>(readBuffer[0]) << 0|
    static_cast<uint64_t>(readBuffer[1]) << 8 |
    static_cast<uint64_t>(readBuffer[2]) << 16 |
    static_cast<uint64_t>(readBuffer[3]) << 24 |
    static_cast<uint64_t>(readBuffer[4]) << 32 |
    static_cast<uint64_t>(readBuffer[5]) << 40 |
    static_cast<uint64_t>(readBuffer[6]) << 48 |
    static_cast<uint64_t>(readBuffer[7]) << 56;
    return value;
}
```

### Second Issue

The Big Endian vs Little Endian! D:!!
    Article describing this problem: http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/
My application file it seemed was using Big Endian. So I had to make this one as well.

```
    long readLongBigEndian(char * readBuffer, int length) {
    long value = 
            (((long)readBuffer[0] << 56) +
            ((long)(readBuffer[1] & 255) << 48) +
            ((long)(readBuffer[2] & 255) << 40) +
            ((long)(readBuffer[3] & 255) << 32) +
            ((long)(readBuffer[4] & 255) << 24) +
            ((readBuffer[5] & 255) << 16) +
            ((readBuffer[6] & 255) <<  8) +
            ((readBuffer[7] & 255) <<  0));
        return value;
}
```

### Third Issue:

Converting the long to a double. Now I tried standard casting and other methods, however for some reason failed. The following worked every time

```
double longBitsToDouble(long d)
{
    double * pl = reinterpret_cast<double*>(&d);
    return  *pl;
}
```

I hope this helps anyone with any similar issues with reading doubles with ifstream! Cheers

Comment: _"doubles are stored in binary stream as long int"_ What?!?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes it does. Only really noticeable when the interpreter can't make light of the data type automatically (I.E backwards due to Endian issues). However always stored visibly as a long int. Notice the lack of Decimals.

Comment: That makes no sense. The binary representation of a double has no "decimals" - it is ones and zeroes. I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding the input format.

Comment: The data type storage was flipped in endians so casting the binary did not work automatically as the binary ones and zeros positions were flipped. Solution speaks of this.
Issue occurs when converting saved binaries of flash files for example where doubles/floats are stored backwards in binary